# Меняется ли знак из-за смысла?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте .

Моя любовница такая умница() за меня молится, во сне целуется.

Моя любовница такая умница() за меня молится, после целуется.

В первом случае ставится тире , так как перечисление? 
Во втором случае ставится запятая, так как перечисления нет ? Или я не прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, в первом случае лучше поставить двоеточие, так как идет пояснение, в чем, собственно, любовница умница. А во втором — действительно запятую, поскольку идет перечисление достоинств любовницы. Хотя первый вариант будет выглядеть правильнее.

Comment: Спасибо:)!